# TeamViewer enable / disable / start

Tags: daemon, teamviewer

The clients are Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit and the server is Debian Stretch 64-bit.

Having [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com) 11 Free installed both on the server and all clients.

But I don't want for it to silently run on the background for more than one reason.

I wish to be able for it to:

1. Disable
2. Enable
3. Start the client without having the terminal flooded

Note: On my system with TeamViewer 11, after enabling the daemon, the client does not start. Which I actually prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define the following aliases if you do this on every day basis:

1. Disabling the daemon is easy:

   ```
   alias tv-disable='sudo teamviewer daemon disable'
   ```
2. Enabling the daemon is as easy:

   ```
   alias tv-enable='sudo teamviewer daemon enable'
   ```
3. But to start the client without having the terminal flooded, you need to elaborate a little:

   ```
   alias tv-start='/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer > /dev/null 2>&1 &'
   ```